# How do I build my JavaFX Gluon app for iOS now that RoboVM is not available?

Tags: javafx-8, gluon, gluon-mobile

As of April 17th, RoboVM licenses are no longer available. Is there an official production-ready replacement for RoboVM?  I have not seen any changes in the documentation on Gluon's web site for handling iOS. If there's no replacement from Gluon, is there a clear solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Gluon Mobile and the underlying JavaFXPorts project never relied on a commercial license of RoboVM. On the contrary, both relied on the latest open source release: 1.8.0, which you can find [here](https://github.com/robovm/robovm).

Obviously, it is not maintained anymore, and new changes in the iOS SDK are not taken care of.

Based on this release, there are several forks, some of which are trying to include the latest iOS changes and keep it up to the date.

Actually, JavaFXPorts [depends](https://bitbucket.org/gluoncode/javafxmobile-plugin) on one of those forks: [Mobidevelop](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com), [source code](https://github.com/mobidevelop/robovm), and now uses its 2.3.0 version.

So you shouldn't have any issues of building an iOS solution with Gluon Mobile.